# Read hh:mm:ss from Excel properly

Tags: excel, pandas, timestamp

I have a column in my Excel sheet called "Start_Time" and the data in the column is in "HH:MM:SS" format, for example "10:13:20".

But when I use pandas.read_excel() function to load the data. The "Start_Time" column showed decimal values (for example: 0.425925925925926) with data type as "object".

How could make the df["Start_Time"] to display as "10:13:20"?

I tried pd.Timedelta(), but it works for only one value at a time. I want to convert all values in that column.

| Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- |
| 16:24:50 | 16:32:27 |
|  | 10:35:53 |
| 15:06:46 | 15:21:43 |
| 6:39:50 | 6:39:50 |
| 21:55:02 |  |
| 3:29:04 | 3:29:13 |
| 0:53:06 | 0:53:06 |
| 10:21:13 | 10:25:18 |
| 16:15:25 | 16:19:31 |

Comment: can you share sample excel? I tried and unable to reproduce the issue

Comment: Thanks, I just added a sample data in the post.

Comment: Thanks! can you link your sample excel?

Comment: :). I can't share it since it's private data. Thanks though. I used pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'],unit = "d", errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'). Then, I dropped all the nan. It worked. :) :)

Comment: related: [Pandas problem with a column with mixed time and date time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70858332/10197418), [Python Datetime conversion for excel dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74205015/10197418)

Answer (score 0):

Excel stores the date as a serial number counting from a starting date.

When you choose a format it converts that serial number to the format demanded.

If you want Pandas to display the correct date then you have to convert the serial number.